# Multilinear map is continuous iff it is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

A multilinear map is defined as follows :

A $~k$-linear operator $~T:X_1\times \dots \times X_k \to Y$ is a map that is separately linear in each variables. The map $T$ is said to be bounded, if there exists a positive constant $C$ such that  $\|T(x_1, \dots, x_k)\|\leq C\|x_1\|\dots\|x_k\|$ for all $(x_1,\dots,x_k)\in X_1\times \dots \times X_k.$ In that case the norm of $T$ is defined by $\|T\|=sup\{\|T(x_1,\dots, x_k)\|:~\|x_1\|=\dots=\|x_k\|=1\}.$ The product space $X_1\times \dots \times X_k$ is always equipped with the product topology.

Now, I want to prove that, `` Every multilinear map is bounded if and only if it is continuous." Please help me to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A hint along the lines is: Try to prove that if $T$ is continuous at $\left( 0, 0, \cdots, 0 \right)$, then it is continuous everywhere. If you could prove this, then I think the proof of what you want will be analogous to the case of bounded linear operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T:X_1\times X_2 \times ...\times X_k\to Y $ is $k$ linear and continous then there exists open balls $B_{X_1} (0,r) , ... , B_{X_k} (0,r) $ such that $(x_1,...,x_k)\in B_{X_1} (0,r) \times ... \times B_{X_k} (0,r) $ implies $$||T(x_1, ..., x_k)||_Y \leq 1.$$
Now take any $(v_1, ..., v_k)\in X_1\times X_2 \times ...\times X_k$ then the element $$\left(\frac{rv_1}{2||v_1 ||_{X_1}},\frac{rv_2}{2||v_2 ||_{X_2}},...,\frac{rv_k}{2||v_k ||_{X_k}}\right)$$ belongs to $$B_{X_1} (0,r) , ... , B_{X_k} (0,r) $$ and therefore
$$\left|\left|T\left(\frac{rv_1}{2||v_1 ||_{X_1}},\frac{rv_2}{2||v_2 ||_{X_2}},...,\frac{rv_k}{2||v_k ||_{X_k}}\right)\right|\right|_{Y}\leq 1$$ which implies $$||T(v_1 ,...,v_k )||_{Y}\leq \frac{2}{r} ||v_1||_{X_1}\cdot ...\cdot ||v_k ||_{X_k}$$
thus $T$ is bounded.

On the other asume that $T$ is bounded. We have $$||T(x_1 ,..., x_k) - T(u_1, ...u_k)||_{Y}\leq ||T(x_1-u_1 , x_2 ,....,x_k ||_Y +||T(u_1 , x_2 , .., x_k )-T(u_1,u_2, ...u_k)||_{Y}\leq...\leq ||T(x_1-u_1 , x_2 ,....,x_k ||_Y +||T(u_1 , x_2 -u_2 ,x_3 .., x_k )||_{Y}+...+||T(u_1,u_2, ...,x_k -u_k)||_{Y} \leq C||x_1 -u_1 ||_{X_1} \cdot ||x||_{X_2} ...\cdot ||xx_k ||_{X_k} + C ||u_1||_{X_1} \cdot ||x_2 -u_2 ||_{X_2 } \cdot ...\cdot ||x_k ||_{X_k} +....+C||u_1 ||_{X_1 } \cdot ||u_2 ||_{X_2 } \cdot ...\cdot ||x_k -u_k ||_{X_k}$$
hence if $(x_1 , ..., x_k )\to (u_1 , ..., u_k) $ then by the above inequality $T(x_1,...,x_k )\to T(u_1, ...u_k ) $ and thus $T$ is continous.